# Given list of 2d points, find the point closest to all other points

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

```
Input: list of 2d points (x,y) where x and y are integers.

Distance: distance is defined as the Manhattan distance. 
    ie:
    def dist(p1,p2) 
         return abs(p1.x-p2.x) + abs(p1.y - p2.y)
```

What is an efficient algorithm to find the point that is closest to all other points.

I can only think of a brute force O(n^2) solution:

```
minDist=inf
bestPoint = null
for p1 in points:
    dist = 0
    for p2 in points:
        dist+=distance(p1,p2)
    minDist = min(dist,minDist)
    bestPoint = argmin(p1, bestPoint)
```

basically look at every pair of points.

Comment: This is not the euclidean distance, you need to square each (p1.x - p2.x) and (p1.y - p2.y), and take a square root of the summation. The method `dist()` is manhattan distances.

Comment: Oops I didn't mean euclidean distance. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that in 1-D the point that minimizes the sum of distances to all the points is the median.

In 2-D the problem can be solved in `O(n log n)` as follows:

Create a sorted array of x-coordinates and for each element in the array compute the "horizontal" cost of choosing that coordinate. The horizontal cost of an element is the sum of distances to all the points projected onto the X-axis. This can be computed in linear time  by scanning the array twice (once from left to right and once in the reverse direction). Similarly create a sorted array of y-coordinates and for each element in the array compute the "vertical" cost of choosing that coordinate.

Now for each point in the original array, we can compute the total cost to all other points in `O(1)` time by adding the horizontal and vertical costs. So we can compute the optimal point in `O(n)`. Thus the total running time is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: The part I was sure of is the initial assertion: "in 1d the point that minimizes the sum of distances to all points is the median". If this is indeed true, we can solve this problem in O(n) by using the linear time median algorithm.

Comment: Yes in 1-D it can be solved in linear time. But in 2-D the problem is that the point: (<median of the x-coordinates>, <median of the y-coordinates>) may not be an input point.

Comment: This is the "center of mass" argument again: It needs a flat (and dense) distribution of points

Comment: @EugenRieck I don't understand what you mean. I am not computing the center of mass.

Comment: An algorithm, that searches the lowest-cost point with concepts such as median, average, etc. implies, that the average/median point is part of the set - this is not given (and the ring example shows, that searching the nearest point can be non-trivial)

Comment: I only mentioned median as a solution for 1-D (which is true). For 2-D, I am travelling through each point and computing the distance of that point to all the points using the precomputed horizontal and vertical distances. The point I return is always present in the input set.

Comment: The original problem is to find a point in the set that is closest to other sets. So this gets rid of the problem where median might not find optimal in case where optimal is not part of the set.

Comment: For the initial part of your answer, ` in 1-D the point that minimizes the sum of distances to all the points is the median`, I don't quite understand. Why?

Comment: @Alcott At median the number of points to the left is equal to the number of points to the right. Suppose the sum of distances to all points at the median is D. If you move your solution right by one point (located at distance d ), then your cost becomes D + d*(n/2+1) - d*(n/2-1).

Comment: Didn't see how your algorithm is done in O(nlogn). Based on your description, you compute horizontal/vertical costs for each elem in the array, this costs O(n). And there are n such elems, which renders O(n^2). Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Once we compute and STORE the horizontal and vertical costs for each element, getting the total cost of a point just requires two constant time lookups.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is [center of mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass).

You basically add all xs' and ys' together and divide be the mass of the whole system. 
Now, You have uniform mass less particles let their mass be 1.

then all you have to do is is sum the location of the particles and divide by the number of particles.

say we have p1(1,2) p2(1,1) p3 (1,0)

```
// we sum the x's 

    bestXcord = (1+1+1)/3 = 1

//we sum the y's 

    bestYcord = (2+1)/3 = 1
```

so p2 is the closest.

solved in O(n)

Comment: Not exactly. The center of mass does not have to be a point from the set, while the requirements say the point you seek must be from the set. For example, `(0,2),(0,0)` - you cannot chose `(0,1)` as the answer. I suspect the point closest to the center of mass will do - but can you prove it?

Comment: It is not perfect I agree. The correlation struck as so beautiful I had to put it as an answer

Comment: Of course, another pass on the set of points to find the one closest to the "center of mass" would still make this O(n)

Comment: From second thaught, no - it will definetly not do. Think of: `(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(5000,0),(10000,0)`. `15,000/5=3,000`. The closest is `(5000,0)` which the sum of distances to is `20000`. While if chosing (0,0) the sum will be 15000

Comment: The center of mass argument works only, if you have an approximately flat distribution - it breaks e.g. on rings (a tiny variance in the mass distribution makes one of the many inner points the best).

Comment: Intuitively we are looking for the average of distances. We can neglect the mass and we basically take the average of point positions.

Comment: We can still use the algorithm to take the closest actual point. 
going over the points again looking for the closest value that exists.

Comment: @EugenRieck Thank you for pointing that out.
 From the gist of the question I was thinking it's a list of arbitrary points this way it can work most of the time.

Comment: This solution is basically finding the average. The average suffers from outliers skewing.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your initial algortihm, there is an optimization possible:

```
minDist=inf
bestPoint = null
for p1 in points:
    dist = 0
    for p2 in points:
        dist+=distance(p1,p2)
        //This will weed out bad points rather fast
        if dist>=minDist then continue(p1)
    /*
    //Unnecessary because of new line above
    minDist = min(dist,minDist)
    bestPoint = argmin(p1, bestPoint)
    */
    bestPoint = p1
```

The idea is, to throw away outliers as fast as possible. This can be improved more:

- start p1 loop with a heuristic "inner" point (This creates a good `minDist` first, so worse points get thrown away faster)
- start p2 loop with heuristic "outer" points (This makes `dist` rise fast, possibly triggering the exit condition faster

If you trade size for speed, you can go another route:

```
//assumes points are numbered 0..n
dist[]=int[n+1]; //initialized to 0
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  for (j=i+1;j<=n;j++) {
    dist=dist(p[i], p[j]);
    dist[i]+=dist;
    dist[j]+=dist;
  }
minDist=min(dist);
bestPoint=p[argmin(dist)];
```

which needs more space for the dist array, but calculates each distance only once. This has the advantage to be better suited to a "get the N best points" sort of problem and for calculation-intensive metrices. I suspect it would bring nothing for the manhattan metric, on an x86 or x64 architecture though: The memory access would heavily dominate the calculation.