# Finding the horizontal cost (and vertical cost) of an element?

Tags: algorithm, distance

I was browsing Stack Overflow for a question on an algorithm in which to find the closest point to point A from a list of 2D points. I know the list must be sorted to get an optimal time, but I want it faster than O(N**2) which would be using brute force.

I found an answer that seems appealing here: [Given list of 2d points, find the point closest to all other points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12905663/#12905913), but I don't fully understand the answer. I am wondering about the part where he begins explaining about the horizontal/vertical cost and from that point onward. Could someone provide me an example of what to do in the case of these (random) points?

point A: (20, 40.6)
List of Points[(-20,200),(12,47), (4,0), (-82,92), (40,15), (112, 97), (-203, 84)]

If you can provide an alternative method to the linked post that would also be fine. I know it has something to do with sorting the list, and probably taking out the extremes, but again I'm not sure what method(s) to use.

EDIT: I understand now that this is not the euclidian distance that I am most interested in.  Would a divide and conquer algorithm/method be the best bet here? I don't fully understand it yet, but it sounds like it solves what I want it to solve in O(N*log(N)). Would this approach be optimal, and if so would someone mind breaking it down to the basics as I am unable to understand it as most other sites have described it.

Comment: Note that the question you refer to asks for closest points in an unusual norm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry ) instead of the typical euclidean distances. The algorithm in the answer also only works because the distance between two points is the sum of the horizontal distance and vertical distance. So the question might not actually be related to your problem.

Comment: So what you are saying is that this is calculating the closest point in not necessarily the way I may want to define it as being closest (like using the distance formula, but instead is using another method)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search more browsing material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to do is not possible if there is no structure in the list of points and they can really be random. Assume you have an algorithm that runs faster than in linear time, then in in your list of points there is one point `B` that is not read at all by the algorithm. Necessarily if I change `B` to another value the algorithm will run in the same way and return the same result. Now if the algorithm does not return a point of the list that is the same than `A` then I can change `B` to `B=A` and the correct solution to the problem would now be `B` (you can't get any closer than actually being the same point) and the algorithm would necessarily return a wrong result.

What the question you are referring to is trying to do is find a point `A` **out of** a list `L` such that sum of all distances between `A` and every point in `L` is minimal. The algorithm described in the answer runs in time `O(n*log(n))` (where `n`). Note that [`n*log(n)` actually grows faster than `n`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*log%28x%29,%20x%20,%20from%20x=1%20to%20x=100)  so it is actually slower than looking at every element.

Also "distance" in the question does not refer to the euclidean distance. Where normally you would define the distance between a point `(x_1,y_1)` and a second point `(x_2,y_2)` to be `sqrt((x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-x_2)^2)` the question refers to the "[Taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)" `|x_2-x_1|+|y_2-x_2|` where `| |` refers to the absolute value.

#### Re: edit

If you just want to find one point of the list that is closest to a fixed point `A` than you can linearly search for it in the list. See the following python code:

```
def distance(x,y):
    #Manhatten distance
    x1,x2=x
    y1,y2=y
    return abs(x1-y1)+abs(x2-y2)

def findClosest(a,listOfPoints):
    minDist=float("inf")
    minIndex=None
    for index,b in enumerate(listOfPoints):
        if distance(a,b) < minDist:
            minDist=distance(a,b)
            minIndex=index
    return minDist,minIndex

a=(20, 40.6)
listOfPoints=[(-20,200),(12,47), (4,0), (-82,92), (40,15), (112, 97), (-203, 84)]

minDist,minIndex=findClosest(a,listOfPoints)
print("minDist:",minDist)
print("minIndex:",minIndex)
print("closest point:",listOfPoints[minIndex])
```

The challenge of the referenced question is that you don't want to minimize the distance to a fixed point, but that you want to find a point `A` **out of** the list `L` whose **average distance to all other points in `L`** is minimal.

Comment: Thank you for that description and you are right. My question was actually poorly described ( I will improve it). I would vote your comment up, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @user3529578 No problem. Just mark the answer as accepted if you have no further questions. (I've edited it in reply to your edit.)